# Cannot redeclare block-scoped variable 'lia'

Tags: typescript

i just start typescript and at first step i get this err

Cannot redeclare block-scoped variable 'lia'.

i try run it in vscode by tsc nameoffile.ts

an it dosent give me any thing just underline the lia

```
let lia = {name:"ali", age :35}
console.log("hello world!");
console.log(lia);
```

and this is my code

Comment: Please provide a [mre]. There are no issues in the [code block posted](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/DYUwLgBMCWCGEF4IG8B2sC2IBcAiWMuANBLAOYgTYDMArAL4BQAxgPaoDOroAdMK2QAUuABYhg-CAHdWAJ2AATAIS4AlAG4W7Lr35CYsDUA).